# Reading in a file, loading correctly but not formatting correctly

Tags: matlab, readfile

I can't figure out why I'm getting an error when I try to format my file in a certain way. The following code loads my file correctly, but it loads it as a 12x1 array.

```
disp(strcat('Navi_Endo_RefHomMat_', num2str(i), '.txt'))
Navi_HomMat_File_ID = fopen(strcat('Navi_Endo_RefHomMat_', num2str(i), '.txt'));
Navi_Endo_RefHomMat(i,:) = textscan(Navi_HomMat_File_ID,'%f');
fclose(Navi_HomMat_File_ID);
```

I want it to load as a 3x4 array though. When I try doing the following, I get an error "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts"

```
disp(strcat('Navi_Endo_RefHomMat_', num2str(i), '.txt'))
Navi_HomMat_File_ID = fopen(strcat('Navi_Endo_RefHomMat_', num2str(i), '.txt'));
Navi_Endo_RefHomMat(i,:) = textscan(Navi_HomMat_File_ID,'%f %f %f %f');
fclose(Navi_HomMat_File_ID);
```

My text file looks like this

```
   7.8466354e-01  -9.7684133e-02  -6.1201847e-01  -1.6701139e+01
   4.6962973e-01   7.3803591e-01   4.8431043e-01  -2.0213967e+02
   4.0442146e-01  -6.6750767e-01   6.2504598e-01  -1.7367594e+02
   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00
```

I know I could easily change my variable my reshaping it to get a 3x4, but I want to read it in correctly without having to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this line:

```
Navi_Endo_RefHomCell = textscan(Navi_HomMat_File_ID, '%f %f %f %f');
```

You will end up with a cell `Navi_Endo_RefHomCell` but you can use [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) to solve this.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the difference between what you're suggesting and what I tried the second time. The code I tried the second time is the 2nd box of code. It looks like the same as you are suggesting...but gives the error "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts"

Comment: Oh nvm, I see you just pulle dthe (i,:) out, thanks it works =)